# Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection *13 and *14 not connected, how do i connect it back?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, lan

This is what I see:

[image]

I am trying to change my IP address using ipconfg/renew, but it is not allowing me to because my Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection *13 and *14 are not connected, can anyone tell me how to connect it?

This is what I get when I run the command:

[image]

Comment: There is so very little information here that I don't think that anyone can.  Please take [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and learn [how to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: would it help if i put an image?

Comment: Look in Device Manager to see if the device is working. If working it should connect to an access point. Make sure other devices can connect to the access point.

Comment: Your images don't really add much information. We need to know more information about the wireless networks you're trying to connect to, your system setup, etc. It is not super normal to connect to multiple wireless network simultaneously, so we're not even sure that you've proven you have a real problem here. Please use the EDIT button and spend some time explaining further what your setup looks like, what is failing, what the symptoms of the failure are, why this indicates something is actually broken, etc.